# Read all the text files in directory and writing the data in one json file

Tags: python-3.x

I am reading all text files from one particular directory and writing them into one json file. 
I have the errors as : expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list. Can someone know how to solve this? Thank you

```
import json
import glob

filepath = glob.glob( "path/*.txt")
line = []
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    print(line)
    cnt = 1

    while line:
        print("Object {}: {}".format(cnt, line.split(',')))
        line = line.split(',')
        #print(line)
        data= []
        try:
            data.append({
                'FileName': filepath,
                'bbox_left': line[0],
                'bbox_top': line[1],
                'bbox_width': line[2],
                'bbox_height': line[3],
                'Score': line[4],
                'Object_category': line[5],
                'Truncation': line[6],
                'Occlusion': line[7]
            })
            with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
                json.dump(data, outfile)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        line = fp.readline()
        cnt += 1
```

Comment: `filepath = glob.glob( "path/*.txt")` will return you a list of the files. you then do `with open(filepath) as fp:` so your giving a list of the file names to open. but open cant open multiple files at once like that. instaed you should iterate over the lsit of files and call open on each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

filepath here is a list of 'filepaths', not just one 'filepath', and so the `open()` complains that it accepts a string and not a list

your code should look like this, i've modified it a bit so take your time to see what happened

```
import json
import glob

filepaths = glob.glob("path/*.txt")
line = []
data = []
for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        for cnt, line in enumerate(fp.readlines()):
            line = line.split(',')
            print("Object {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
            try:
                data.append({
                    'FileName': filepath,
                    'bbox_left': line[0],
                    'bbox_top': line[1],
                    'bbox_width': line[2],
                    'bbox_height': line[3],
                    'Score': line[4],
                    'Object_category': line[5],
                    'Truncation': line[6],
                    'Occlusion': line[7]
                })
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Comment: Seems something wrong, As it doesn't even open my json file and closes automatically and the lines from text aren't reading in order so I am not sure if all the lines are read from text file

Comment: @NayeemMuddinKhan can you upload a sample of those text files?

Comment: The text files look like this 684,8,273,116,0,0,0,0 <newline>
406,119,265,70,0,0,0,0<newline>
255,22,119,128,0,0,0,0<newline>
1,3,209,78,0,0,0,0<newline>
708,471,74,33,1,4,0,1<newline>
639,425,61,46,1,4,0,0<newline>
594,399,64,51,1,4,0,0<newline>
562,390,61,38,1,4,0,0<newline>
540,372,65,33,1,4,0,1<newline>
514,333,68,35,1,4,0,0<newline>

Comment: @NayeemMuddinKhan i tested it now and it works, make sure you have the path and input files extension correct

Comment: Well the json file is generated but its a problem to open the file

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Text editor hangs up when I open the json file, I have around 6471 text files of about 30 average lines in every text file

Comment: @NayeemMuddinKhan this is not related to the code nor the json file, simply the json file is soo big and can't fit into the ram, you can solve this by saving the data in multiple json files.

Comment: Okay I will check, Thank you